# Compiling error while using CGAL with Boost on Windows with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, windows, boost, visual-studio-2017, cgal

I'm trying to use CGAL-4.13.1 on my Windows machine with Visual Studio 2017. I followed CGALs instructions for installing on Windows([1](https://www.cgal.org/download/windows.html)), after that I tried some code examples([2](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/tutorial_hello_world.html)). The first and second worked correctly but the third didn't. To be more precise once I had to use

`#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>`.

I got the following error messages:

> E0135  "class "boost::mpl::sequence_tag<boost::mpl::list <boost::mpl::na, (followed by 19 times boost::mpl::na,)>>"" has no Member ""type"". cgal_test   C:\local\boost_1_70_0\boost\mpl\begin_end.hpp   45
>
> E0135  "namespace "boost::mpl::aux"" has no Member ""list_tag"".   cgal_test   C:\local\boost_1_70_0\boost\mpl\list\aux_\item.hpp  48
>
> E0070  an incomplete type is not allowed.  cgal_test   C:\local\boost_1_70_0\boost\mpl\sequence_tag.hpp    111

and many LNK2019: unresolved external symbol errors

I suspect there's an error with the way I include the boost files. But I cant make much more out of the error messages or what I'm supposed to do.
Can someone help me or know what I should do?

Comment: You need to link with `libboost-thread and libboost-system` libraries.

Comment: @VictorGubin these are compiler errors not linker errors

Comment: @VictorGubin linking the libraries didn't help and resulted in the same error, but thanks for answering.

Comment: I would try an older version of boost (say 1.69 for instance), though I can't promise that will help.